# Facebook authentication and redirect ur

Tags: java, javascript, facebook-authentication

I have a scenrario where a user click to view a secure page, so hits the sigin page.
I have a Facebook authentication script on the sign in page as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginUsingOAUTH()
{
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=${facebookAppId}&redirect_uri=http://${pageContext.request.serverName}/account/facebook/signin&scope=email&display=popup", "mywindow","location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0, width=580,height=300");
}
</script>
```

When the user is authenticated the script redirects him to the homepage. But I want the user to be redirected back to the page he was browsing.

How can I change my current script to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is that Java or Javascript? Java and Javascript are _very_ different.

Comment: Sorry, well the website is based on java

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the URL you want to save to go back with

```
var doc = document;
var url = doc.URL;
```

and then set it globally so you can access it when the script reloads on a page change

```
GM_setValue("URL",url);
```

then when you need to retrieve the saved URL you use

```
old_url = GM_getValue("URL");
```

Then you can do this to change to the previous page

```
window.location = old_url;
```